# Can not launch Eclipse - JVM terminated. Exit code=1

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

I installed Java Open JRE and JDK on Ubuntu 14.04 using following commands;

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

When I try to launch Eclipse, following error keep popping up.

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /home/mani/Downloads/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.100.v20180827-1352.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /home/mani/Downloads/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.9.0.20180917-1800/splash.bmp
-launcher /home/mani/Downloads/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/mani/Downloads/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.800.v20180827-1352/eclipse_1705.so
-startup /home/mani/Downloads/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.100.v20180827-1352.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 288019
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-jar /home/mani/Downloads/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.100.v20180827-1352.jar
```

*My **eclipse.ini** file is like*

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.100.v20180827-1352.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.800.v20180827-1352
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

Please help me to solve this since I have tried some several solutions but still it keeps popping up. java version is like follows

*java version "1.7.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.14) (7u181-2.6.14-0ubuntu0.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.181-b01, mixed mode)*

Comment: take e look inside the log for more info, probably the answer is there ;) --> https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F

Comment: Thanks . I updated my java version 7 to 11 and now it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of Eclipse you are trying to use requires at least Java 8, Java 7 will not work.

Comment: Thank you so much greg-449. That was the issue. I updated the java 7 to 11 and now it's working smoothly. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use eclispe with jdk 7. change `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8` to `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7` in your **eclipse.ini** file